# Get seller, publisher, or brand url from Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: rest, amazon-product-api

I'm using the ItemLookup Operation from Amazon Product Advertising API and I want to retrieve a url for the item's brand, seller, or publisher with my tracking id. I don't see it as part of any of the response groups.

Here is a picture with an arrow pointing to the link I want to get with my tracking id.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the response from the Amazon API. See also the DetailPageURL value in the response

Comment: The detail page url simply brings you to the page pictured in my question. It doesn't provide you with the value I'm asking for.

Comment: Whats the url of the page

Comment: I want to programmatically generate the 'seller' page from the Product Advertising API information ItemLookup information. I don't know what 'url' you're asking for.